# output different elements from two arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to output different elements from two arrays. So if i have an array A: `{9, 0, 1}` and B is `{0, 8, 1}`, I need to output an element which included in the first set, but are not included in the second :`9` Can not think how I should compare all elements from the first array with the second one.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a[10],b[10],c,n,i,j;

    printf("enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("Enter a[%d]: ",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    printf("Enter b[%d]: ",j+1);
    scanf("%d",&b[j]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d ", a[i]); }

            printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            printf("%d ", b[i]); }
            printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

I'd like to show my thoughts but i think it's stupid:

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(a[i]!= b[j]){
                c=a[i];
            }
        }
    printf("%d ",c);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean output all elements that are *in common* between the two arrays? In your description you say "different elements" but in your example you output the elements that are the same in the arrays.

Comment: @GovindParmar SORRY!!!!! I've edited

Comment: Do you have any other constraints of the arrays? All integers can appear as values?

Comment: @StoryTeller no, that is it.

Comment: For debugging this, you should hard code your test case, so you don't need to type the input on each run.

Comment: You should always check result of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a more efficient solution, as suggested by @Sumeet Singh, you can sort the second array with [`qsort`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_qsort.htm), then  find similar elements from the first array with [`bsearch`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_bsearch.htm)(binary search).

Your current solution is **O(N^2)** time, which will be very slow with large `n`, but you can achieve more efficiency with this approach.

Here is some code I wrote up with demonstrates this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NNUMBERS 10

void get_array_input(int array1[], int array2[], size_t *n);
void search_elements(int array1[], int array2[], size_t n);
void print_arrays(int array[], size_t n);
int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void) {
    int array1[NNUMBERS], array2[NNUMBERS];
    size_t n;

    /* input from user */
    get_array_input(array1, array2, &n);

    printf("\nFirst array: ");
    print_arrays(array1, n);

    printf("\nSecond array: ");
    print_arrays(array2, n);

    /* sorting the second array */
    qsort(array2, n, sizeof(*array2), cmp_func);

    printf("\nSorted Second array: ");
    print_arrays(array2, n);

    /* the search begins */
    search_elements(array1, array2, n);

    return 0;
}

void get_array_input(int array1[], int array2[], size_t *n) {
    size_t i;

    printf("Enter n: ");
    if (scanf("%zu", n) != 1) {
        printf("Invalid n value.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        printf("Enter array1[%zu]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &array1[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalud array value.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++) {
        printf("Enter array2[%zu]: ", i);
        if (scanf("%d", &array2[i]) != 1) {
            printf("Invalud array value.\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void search_elements(int array1[], int array2[], size_t n) {
    size_t i;
    void *key;

    printf("\nElements in first array which are not in second array: ");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        key = bsearch(&array1[i], array2, n, sizeof(*array2), cmp_func);
        if (!key) {
            printf("%d ", array1[i]); /* not found, so print it */
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void print_arrays(int array[], size_t n) {
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

/* cmp function needed for qsort and bsearch */
/* many ways to write these */
int cmp_func(const void *a, const void *b) {
    const int *num1 = (const int *)a;
    const int *num2 = (const int *)b;

    if (*num1 > *num2) {
        return +1;
    } else if (*num1 < *num2) {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
Enter n: 3
Enter array1[0]: 9
Enter array1[1]: 0
Enter array1[2]: 1
Enter array2[0]: 0
Enter array2[1]: 8
Enter array2[2]: 1
```

Output:

```
First array: 9 0 1

Second array: 0 8 1

Sorted Second array: 0 1 8

Elements in first array which are not in second array: 9
```

Answer (score 4):

This can be easily solved using **Binary search**. Follow the simple steps.

**Step 1**: Sort the second array.

**Step 2**: For each element of the first array, binary search it in the second array, if its not present , print it, otherwise dont.

The time complexity is **O(m log n)**, where `m` is length of first array and `n` is length of second array.

Comment: `O((m+n)*log(n))` to include the time for sorting

Comment: Nice answer, I wrote some code in one of the answers to test this out. Definitely a very efficient approach.

Comment: If you are going to sort, then it's best to sort both. For instance, sort both descending. If `a[i]<b[j]`, you won't find any other `a[k]>a[i]` such that `a[k]==b[j]`, so you can exclude the possibility of having `b[j]` in `a`. If `a[i]>b[j]`, then you can exclude the possibility of having `a[i]` in `b`. The Big-O is the same, but now you traverse both arrays sequentially.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path. You are taking each value from the first array and comparing to each value in the second.

What you need to do now is to only print `a[i]` if there isn't any `b[j]` such that they are the same. The easiest  way is to set a flag (say, `unique=1`). You can give this flag any name you find suitable, but in this case I'm thinking it says that the number `a[i]` is "unique" to the array `a`. So in this case you start with the premise that, yes, you won't find `a[i]` in the array`b`, and then you try to disprove your assumption. If at any time of you search you find an instance of `a[i] == b[j]`, then your premise was wrong, so you set `unique=0`.

After you have compared this `a[i]` against all elements in `b`, you review your flag. And you print the appropriate message depending on whether you found this element in `b` or not.

Note that this assumes that the same value doesn't appear twice in `a`.

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code a little bit and this code gives you desired output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
        int a[10],b[10],c,n,i,j;
        int counter=0;
        printf("enter a number: ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                printf("Enter a[%d]: \n",i+1);
                scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                printf("Enter b[%d]: \n",j+1);
                scanf("%d",&b[j]);
        }
        for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                counter=0;
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                        if(a[i]!=b[j]){
                                counter++;
                        }
                }
                if(counter == n){
                        printf("%d ",a[i]);
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Let's explain this code a little bit:
In the last nested for loop, outer loop takes one element from array a. Inner loop gets every element of array b in order to compare it to taken element from array a. If none of the elements of array b is equal to a's taken element, counter will be equal to n(array size). Then we can print this element taken from a(it means there is no match between this taken element and array b's all of elements.

Comment: Thank for your help, i think i was close to you, but i couldnt think to it. Thank you one more time!